# Project Tango Android App Not Tracking Camera

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, camera, motion, tango

I have installed Unity 5.6.1f1 and Android Studio, imported the Tango package and opened the motion tracking example scene but when I build out the scene the app does not move with the camera? The Tango cube simply sits there with a white background no matter where I move the camera.

I would really appreciate any help with this as I am testing this for a business solution and would love to get it working.

Comment: Are you testing on a Tango enabled device?

Comment: Actually I'm not... I'm using an NVidia Shield which is probably the problem!